# How can I make Adobe Flex run faster?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

Compared to native apps, my Flex application runs like a hog born by a snail, especially on mobile devices. What tricks can I employ to optimize it's performance, and what trap doors should I avoid?

Comment: Please edit your question to be less vague and maybe include an example.

Comment: I don't know how to make Flex faster, but if you want your app to run faster on mobile devices, I have the perfect solution for you, don't use flex or flash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a better architecture, simplify your code, avoid using non-mobile optimized components, be smart about GC, renderers, binding and using often recurring events, use better libraries (TweenLite instead of adobe tween libs), avoid heavy graphics or animations.

The list goes on.  Most of these are all PEBKAC though.  I've seen some decent performance from Flex on mobile, but it all depends how you code it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step could be to ensure you build your application using release mode, not debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm down voting you and ask you to write a specific question.  You have not provided any information for anyone to provide you a reasonable response.

But here is some information.

1) Flex AMF data transfer is faster than XML, AJAX and JSON.

2) If you are comparing Flex to Assembler language in terms of speed, you might want to rethink why you are using a cross platform high level language.